# Get the contacts list from phone and display it using RecyclerView and implement SearchView functionality to search

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, contacts, searchview

In this I am able to get the details of my contacts. But not using RecyclerView. It is using ListView. It is using SimpleCursorAdapter. I don't know how to use SimpleCursorAdapter in RecyclerView. I know how to use RecyclerView with constants String to display. But in this I want to retrieve data using Contacts DB.
Please Help me I am new to android. I don't know how to implement this.

Thanks in advance

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;
MatrixCursor mMatrixCursor;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
    mMatrixCursor = new MatrixCursor(new String[] { "_id","name","photo","details"} );

    // Adapter to set data in the listview
    mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(),
            R.layout.lv_layout,
            null,
            new String[] { "name","photo","details"},
            new int[] { R.id.tv_name,R.id.iv_photo,R.id.tv_details}, 0);

    // Getting reference to listview
    ListView lstContacts = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lst_contacts);

    // Setting the adapter to listview
    lstContacts.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    // Creating an AsyncTask object to retrieve and load listview with contacts
    ListViewContactsLoader listViewContactsLoader = new ListViewContactsLoader();

    // Starting the AsyncTask process to retrieve and load listview with contacts
    listViewContactsLoader.execute();
}
private class ListViewContactsLoader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Cursor> {

    @Override
    protected Cursor doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Uri contactsUri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;

        // Querying the table ContactsContract.Contacts to retrieve all the contacts
        Cursor contactsCursor = getContentResolver().query(contactsUri, null, null, null,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC ");

        if(contactsCursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                long contactId = contactsCursor.getLong(contactsCursor.getColumnIndex("_ID"));

                Uri dataUri = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;

                // Querying the table ContactsContract.Data to retrieve individual items like
                // home phone, mobile phone, work email etc corresponding to each contact
                Cursor dataCursor = getContentResolver().query(dataUri, null,
                        ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=" + contactId,
                        null, null);

                String displayName="";
                String nickName="";
                String homePhone="";
                String mobilePhone="";
                String workPhone="";
                String photoPath="" + android.R.drawable.alert_dark_frame;
                byte[] photoByte=null;
                String homeEmail="";
                String workEmail="";
                String companyName="";
                String title="";

                if(dataCursor.moveToFirst()){
                    // Getting Display Name
                    displayName = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME ));
                    do{

                        // Getting NickName
                        if(dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("mimetype")).equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Nickname.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE))
                            nickName = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data1"));

                        // Getting Phone numbers
                        if(dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("mimetype")).equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)){
                            switch(dataCursor.getInt(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data2"))){
                                case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME :
                                    homePhone = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                                    break;
                                case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE :
                                    mobilePhone = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                                    break;
                                case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK :
                                    workPhone = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                                    break;
                            }
                        }

                        // Getting EMails
                        if(dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("mimetype")).equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE ) ) {
                            switch(dataCursor.getInt(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data2"))){
                                case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_HOME :
                                    homeEmail = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                                    break;
                                case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_WORK :
                                    workEmail = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                                    break;
                            }
                        }

                        // Getting Organization details
                        if(dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("mimetype")).equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)){
                            companyName = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                            title = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data4"));
                        }

                        // Getting Photo
                        if(dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("mimetype")).equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)){
                            photoByte = dataCursor.getBlob(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data15"));

                            if(photoByte != null) {
                                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(photoByte, 0, photoByte.length);

                                // Getting Caching directory
                                File cacheDirectory = getBaseContext().getCacheDir();

                                // Temporary file to store the contact image
                                File tmpFile = new File(cacheDirectory.getPath() + "/wpta_"+contactId+".png");

                                // The FileOutputStream to the temporary file
                                try {
                                    FileOutputStream fOutStream = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);

                                    // Writing the bitmap to the temporary file as png file
                                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, fOutStream);

                                    // Flush the FileOutputStream
                                    fOutStream.flush();

                                    //Close the FileOutputStream
                                    fOutStream.close();

                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                photoPath = tmpFile.getPath();
                            }
                        }
                    }while(dataCursor.moveToNext());
                    String details = "";

                    // Concatenating various information to single string
                    if(homePhone != null && !homePhone.equals("") )
                        details = "HomePhone : " + homePhone + "\n";
                    if(mobilePhone != null && !mobilePhone.equals("") )
                        details += "MobilePhone : " + mobilePhone + "\n";
                    if(workPhone != null && !workPhone.equals("") )
                        details += "WorkPhone : " + workPhone + "\n";
                    if(nickName != null && !nickName.equals("") )
                        details += "NickName : " + nickName + "\n";
                    if(homeEmail != null && !homeEmail.equals("") )
                        details += "HomeEmail : " + homeEmail + "\n";
                    if(workEmail != null && !workEmail.equals("") )
                        details += "WorkEmail : " + workEmail + "\n";
                    if(companyName != null && !companyName.equals("") )
                        details += "CompanyName : " + companyName + "\n";
                    if(title != null && !title.equals("") )
                        details += "Title : " + title + "\n";

                    // Adding id, display name, path to photo and other details to cursor
                    mMatrixCursor.addRow(new Object[]{ Long.toString(contactId),displayName,photoPath,details});
                }
            }while(contactsCursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return mMatrixCursor;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result) {
        // Setting the cursor containing contacts to listview
        mAdapter.swapCursor(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: see https://github.com/blandware/android-atleap/blob/master/atleap-core/src/main/java/com/blandware/android/atleap/loader/SimpleCursorRecyclerAdapter.java

Comment: This link is not helping me.

Comment: `Static library support version of the framework's {@link android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter}.`

Comment: do i have to add this class into my project????

Comment: how else can you use it?

Comment: There is no import statement for CursorRecyclerAdapter class

Comment: because it is in the same package

Comment: can u provide me different link with only RecyclerViewSearchView

Comment: RecyclerViewSearchView? what is it?

Comment: RecyclerView to display Contacts and SearchView to search for contacts in RecyclerView.

Comment: there is no such view that is a combination of `RecyclerView` and `SearchView`, all you need is to do the same what you did with a `ListView`

Comment: https://github.com/Wrdlbrnft/Searchable-RecyclerView-Demo . In this link he showed for constant String array and searching that using SearchView at toolbar. In the same way i want to search. Not using Constant array but by using Contacts.

Comment: in my previous comment i wrote what you should do